# Cmake / iOS: find_package(GLUT REQUIRED) does not define GLUT_INCLUDE_DIRS

Tags: ios, opengl-es, frameworks, cmake, glut

First time I use cmake on iOS and I am confused.

```
find_package(GLUT REQUIRED)
```

results in GLUT_LIBRARY and GLUT_FOUND defined (and GLUT_FOUND evaluated to true) but not GLUT_INCLUDE_DIRS as it was suggested here (and many other places):

[How to compile GLUT + OpenGL project with CMake and Kdevelop in linux?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9460242/how-to-compile-glut-opengl-project-with-cmake-and-kdevelop-in-linux)

GLUT_LIBRARY is:

```
/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/MacOSX.platform/Developer/SDKs/MacOSX10.10.sdk/System/Library/Frameworks/GLUT.framework/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/MacOSX.platform/Developer/SDKs/MacOSX10.10.sdk/System/Library/Frameworks/Cocoa.framework
```

I am not familiar with iOS frameworks, so I am not sure if that is what should be expected. How may I find the GLUT include directories ?

Comment: Name of variable is `GLUT_INCLUDE_DIR` (without terminated 'S')

Comment: Afaik there's no glut with opengl es.