# CLion compile glut linux

Tags: c++, cmake, glut, freeglut

I am trying to compile a C++ project on linux which utilizes freeglut.
I can not build the project because the libraries are not linked correctly in the CMake files. I researched and tried to apply what was mentioned in a similar answer here: [How to compile GLUT + OpenGL project with CMake and Kdevelop in linux?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9460242/how-to-compile-glut-opengl-project-with-cmake-and-kdevelop-in-linux)

However build process still fails with the following exception:

```
/opt/JetBrains/apps/CLion/ch-0/181.4668.70/bin/cmake/bin/cmake --build /home/user/Documents/Projects/GdvProject/cmake-build-debug --target testas -- -j 2
CMake Error at CMakeLists.txt:9 (target_link_libraries):
  Cannot specify link libraries for target "GdvProject" which is not built by
  this project.


-- Configuring incomplete, errors occurred!
See also "/home/user/Documents/Projects/GdvProject/cmake-build-debug/CMakeFiles/CMakeOutput.log".
make: *** [Makefile:176: cmake_check_build_system] Error 1
```

My CMakeLists file looks like this:

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 2.8)

project(GdvProject)
add_executable(testas main.cpp)
find_package(OpenGL REQUIRED)
find_package(GLUT REQUIRED)
include_directories( ${OPENGL_INCLUDE_DIRS}  ${GLUT_INCLUDE_DIRS} )

target_link_libraries(GdvProject ${OPENGL_LIBRARIES} ${GLUT_LIBRARY})
```

How can I fix this issue?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Getting a CMake Error: Cannot specify link libraries for target which is not built by the project](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25909943/getting-a-cmake-error-cannot-specify-link-libraries-for-target-which-is-not-bui)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`target_link_libraries` wants a target name. Targets are specified by (among others) `add_executable`, `add_library` and `add_custom_target`.

In other words, `target_link_libraries(testas ...)` should work.
While you're at it, you should consider switching your `include_directories(...)` to `target_include_directories(testas ...)` as well.

Comment: Whats the advantage of switching `include_directories(...)` to `arget_include_directories(testas ...)`?

Comment: Consistency, mostly. It also means that other targets you create in this project do not need to depend on whatever `testas` depends.